# How do I add multiple users to a role in one statement?

Tags: permissions, role, alter-database

I simply want to add multiple users that I have created to a created role then grant all privileges on said role. This is what I have thus far:

```
    CREATE USER Bob FROM LOGIN Bob;
    CREATE USER Billy FROM LOGIN Billy;
    CREATE USER Bobby FROM LOGIN Bobby;
    CREATE ROLE Users;
    ALTER ROLE Users ADD MEMBER Bob;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ABCdatabase.* TO Users;
```

I want to add Billy and Bobby, is there a way to add them to the ALTER line or do I have a create a statement for each members? Any improvements to the code above is helpful.

What kind of SQL server am I using? I am not necessarily using any specific type. I merely need to provide code for a school assignment and am not testing any of this on any particular system. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server: As far as I know ALTER ROLE will add a single member per statement.

If you use the GUI to add [Bob], [Billy] and [Bobby] to the role [Users], you'll see that SQL generates one line for each user and executes them sequentially (ignoring database name):

```
USE [database]
GO
ALTER ROLE [Users] ADD MEMBER [Bob]
GO
USE [database]
GO
ALTER ROLE [Users] ADD MEMBER [Billy]
GO
USE [database]
GO
ALTER ROLE [Users] ADD MEMBER [Bobby]
GO
```

Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189775.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server you can only add a single user per `ALTER ROLE` statement, so your script is about as good as it can get (aside from adding Billy and Bobby to the role).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189775.aspx